# Text displays behind span

Tags: css

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but what I am going to do is when you mouseover a link, a background color slides in from the left. But what I am having issues with is the css. I have a link, and in the link there is a span (which contains the background color). There is then text after it like this:

```
<a href="/info/about"><span></span>About</a>
```

What is happening, is that the text is showing up behind the span. I have tried moving the text in front of the span, but that doesn't work either. What can I do to fix this?

I have the `z-index` for each set as well, and it still doesn't work.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5rnj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.nav-links a span` to have `z-index: -1`. Also, here's the animation in CSS3: http://jsfiddle.net/h5rnj/10/

CSS:

```
.nav-links a span{
    display: block;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in; 
}
.nav-links a:hover span{
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in; 
}
```

Comment: I'd make it faster, that's super slow

Comment: @Zeaklous, it's just an example. Who are we to say how slow/fast he wants it to be? Maybe this website's for sloths.

Comment: I realize that. I was simply suggesting it so the OP knows the value can be changed

Comment: That works perfect! `transition: all 0.3s linear;` I like the css transitions! I was going to do jquery but this is better! Thanks!

Comment: @RyanNaddy, you should also include other browser prefixes (example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14329097/475125) and be aware it won't work in older browsers (compatibility list: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)

Answer (score 2):

It works if you just decrease the `z-index` of `.nav-links a span` from `1` to `-1`.

```css
.nav-links a span{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/jjrH3/)

It works because [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) stacks – each use of `z-index` establishes an independent “stacking context”. The `.nav-links a` has a `z-index: 2`, so everything inside it, including your `span`, is relative to that. The old `z-index` was `1`, which beat the link text's `auto` (0, in relative terms). Now, with a negative `z-index`, the `span` is lower than the link text in the same element.

Note that the behavior is not quite as simple as `z-index` always adding. Each stacking context establishes a new domain where `z-index` values only have meaning relative to each other. For example, on [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/Dfs8D/), the red `div.sub-one` is on top of both its parent and a `div` that its parent is above, even though its `z-index` is `-1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `z-index` of `span`

as

```
.nav-links a span {
z-index: -1
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5rnj/7/)

check this [**Why does z-index: -1; appear above z-index: 1;**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712040/why-does-z-index-1-appear-above-z-index-1)