# Why does transform: scale(xx.y) change from Browser to Browser

Tags: css, css-transforms

**[SOLVED - solution described way below]**

```
#mycontainer {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 30em;
}
```

This mark-up centers.

So, later,

```
$('#mycontainer').css("-webkit-transform", "scale(0.8)");
$('#mycontainer').css("-moz-transform", "scale(0.8)");
$('#mycontainer').css("-ms-transform", "scale(0.8)");
$('#mycontainer').css("-o-transform", "scale(0.8)");
$('#mycontainer').css("transform", "scale(0.8)");
```

The markup does not change, just the "appearance", i.e., it "appears" scaled down.

Is all the above accurate?

And, if so, how do I portably center the object and stop there?

From my testing, Safari does what I want with the code above, whereas the other Browsers also shift the scaled-down object to the right, which is not what I want.

In direct response to your valid comments, here is a jsFiddle to more completely illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2/

But, before you peek at this jsFiddle, let me verbally try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I start out with the standard css for centering a division.  Then, I hook a resize method into the window's onresize Event.  And in that Event, I want to keep the division centered and scale down with the transform center at its default center (50,50); e.g., for scaling to 0.8, that means bringing in the left edge 10% and the right edge 10% keeping the center the same (50,50).

Sounds simple enough ... BUT, the whole division is shifted ... and shifted ONLY when the enclosing window gets super thin ... the division gets scaled down and remains centered UNTIL the window gets really, really thin.

I remember a line in a very, very, very old movie in which the actor blurts out "I'm fading, I'm fading".  *Field of Dreams*.  At this juncture, this sounds like a very appropriate line for me.

Comment: What kind of element is `#mycontainer`? No shift is observed with my FF,Chrome,Safari. I tried `div#mycontainer` with nice centering results.

Comment: Please recreate this issue in the question with a complete example, including HTML. Also, [you can safely leave out most of those prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), and the non-prefixed property should be at the bottom so it gets priority.

Comment: (1) jQuery prefixes CSS properties for you, and (2) don't fall for the vendor prefix trap. There is **no such thing** as `-o-transform` and `-ms-transform`: both Opera and IE support `transform` property as is without vendor prefixes.

Comment: Terry ... I am totally confused by your "no such thing" comment ... reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329084/css-3-transition-prefixes-which-ones-to-use .  One more rid-bit ... "jQuery prefixes CSS properties for you" .  Please cite your source because I'd rejoice to have that be true without having to add more libraries such as prefixFree.

Comment: Note to "Season" ... Notice how the bordered picture (div#mycontainer) scales down (vertically + horizontally) properly with window shrinkage ... until the window gets VERY thin at which point the bordered picture also slides to the right ??? The desired behaviour would have the pic continue to scale down while remaining centered REGARDLESS of how skinny the enclosing window gets

Comment: There's definitely transform properties withy the `-ms-` and `-o-` prefixes. One it quite important for IE9, the other for supporting older version of Opera before they went webkit, probably less necessary to use. The fact that jQuery would auto prefix seems nonsense. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. You should be using CSS to obtain responsive images. Anyways, the problem with your code is that you are trying to scale the conatiner `div` which will at some point become smaller than your image and will cause a negative margin. What you should do instead is to scale the image. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/yL2td3r2/68/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thursday, October 22

Here's the **solution** I promised ...

1) everyone, absolutely everyone who posted above contributed ... everyone.

2) however, special gratitude goes to both "Abhitalks" and "somethinghere".

(a)"Abhitalks" said

> "This seems to be an XY problem".

This "biggee" from Abhitalks turned on the 1st light bulb because when the window became super tiny, and only then, did the #container jump over to the right. It's obvious I wanted a padding left/right = 15%. So ... I put that padding spec in `<body>`.

(b) "somethinghere" turned on the 2nd light bulb when he said

> "So the center point of your container firmly remained at 15em, and it
>   was scaling to that point, which seemed to be more to the right hand
>   side of your screen as your screen size decreased. The trick is to set the transform-origin to 0 0"

So ...

```
body {
    padding: 0em 15%;
}
```

and hooked into my resize routine:

```
var theScale = 0.7*windowWidth/489.6;

if (theScale > 1.0)
{
    theScale = 1.0;
}

/*
    For the sake of speed all transform-origin
    specs are actually in #container's css.
    See the redone jsFiddle below.
*/

theContainer.css("transform-origin", "0 0");
theContainer.css("transform",
                 "scale(" + theScale + ")");
```

Look at my updated jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2/

A sense of euphoria has erupted ... together with "Oh my ... what am I going to do now?"

Answer (score 1):

This seems... kind of a ridiculous solution. You want an image centered in flow, as big as it can get, but never bigger than the window size? Simply use

```
.container { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    max-width: 30em; 
}
```

to receive the desired effect *without* using JS.

The reason you were seeing this is because your were using a set `width` - which means your container was *always* `30em` wide, and its `transform-origin` was defaulted to `50% 50%`.

So the center point of your container firmly remained at 15em, and it was scaling *to that point*, which seemed to be more to the right hand side of your screen as your screen size decreased. That's why it appears to go off to the left - your em will always be 30em wide, so the origin is always `15em` to the left. The trick is to set the `transform-origin` to `0 0` - although the above technique is a lot better and simpeler.

Let's fix your code a bit here (I also removed any reliance on jQuery as this is really not hard in vanilla JS, and removed the ul - this is *just for simplicity* as it makes no difference to the final result in this case):

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){

    var theScale = 0.7 * window.innerWidth / (480 + 9.6);
        theScale = theScale > 1 ? 1 : theScale;
    
    var theContainer = document.getElementById('container');
    
    theContainer.style.msTransform = "scale(" + theScale + ")";
    theContainer.style.mozTransform = "scale(" + theScale + ")";
    theContainer.style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + theScale + ")";
    theContainer.style.oTransform = "scale(" + theScale + ")";
    theContainer.style.transform = "scale(" + theScale + ")";

}, false);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30.00em;
    height: 22.50em;
    border: 0.30em solid #cd853f;
    overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 ;
   -moz-transform-origin: 0 0 ;
   -ms-transform-origin: 0 0 ;
   transform-origin: 0 0 ;
}
#container img {
    /* match specs to #container */
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
<img src="http://lovesongforever.com/My_Love_Song_Forever_Folder/50_images/Nancy_and_John.jpg" alt="At Entrance of CP" />
</section>
```

However, heres my simpeler solution:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 30.00em;
    height: 22.50em;
    border: 0.30em solid #cd853f;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
<img src="http://lovesongforever.com/My_Love_Song_Forever_Folder/50_images/Nancy_and_John.jpg" alt="At Entrance of CP" />
</section>
```